# How to use single domain for multiple projects in OpenShift?

Tags: openshift, redhat, openshift-origin

Scenario like:

- Namespace-1 : example.com/page-1
- Namespace-2 : example.com/page-2

In simple, how to define same domain in 2 different projects using routes on Openshift Platform?

openshift version 3.5

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you could do it with them in different projects. All applications for the same domain would need to be in the same project. So long as you satisfy that requirement, you can use the `route.spec.path` attribute of different route objects for same host name, to route sub URLs to different services.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by [disabling the namespace ownership checks](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/architecture/core_concepts/routes.html#disable-namespace-ownership-check), but *read and understand* the warning!

Of course the above only applies to OpenShift clusters you manage your self, i.e. *not* OpenShift Online.